# How to return the indices of maximum value from an array with python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array and I want to find the indices of the maximum values.

For example:

```
myarray = np.array([1,8,8,3,2])
```

I want to get the result: `[1,2]`, how can I do that?

(Actually I tried `np.argmax(myarray)`, but it only return the first occurrence `[1]`)

Comment: Use `max()` to find the maximum value, then `numpy.where()` to find all the indexes with that value.

Comment: Bet there is a better way, but `np.where(myarray==myarray[np.argmax(myarray)])` works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> myarray = np.array([1,8,8,3,2])
```

You can do:

```
>>> np.where(myarray==myarray[np.argmax(myarray)])
(array([1, 2]),)
```

or,

```
>>> np.where(myarray==max(myarray))
(array([1, 2]),)
```

or,

```
>>> np.nonzero(myarray==max(myarray))
(array([1, 2]),)
```